# Present perfect vs present continuous and grammaticality

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect, present-continuous

I have been listening to this song on repeat for the last couple of months and I still haven't got tired of it.

1. **I've been** listening to this song on repeat **over** the last few months and i still haven't got tired of it.
2. I **have** listened to this song on repeat **over** the last couple of months and I still haven't got tired of it.

Which of these two sentences means the same or is nearest to the meaning of the first, un-numbered sentence? Do both the sentences, 1 and 2 mean the same thing and are all three sentences grammatically correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple questions here.

Firstly, "couple" properly means two, and "few" just means a small number. Informally though, a couple of months might be (very) approximately two.

Secondly "I have" and "I've" are equivalent in meaning, but "I have" is more formal.

Thirdly "I have been listening" and "I have listened" are similar, but not quite the same. The first says the listening has been ongoing or repeated. The second means it has been finished or accomplished. In this context the song has been heard many times for both statements 1 and 2. I feel statement 1 is more natural though. Statement 2 is almost as though I am reporting a task completed.

Fourthly "for the last few months" and "over the last few months" are slightly different. The second one is a weaker statement about the amount of time I have spent listening to it.

So to answer the questions, statement 2 is closer to the original because of the word "couple", and I believe all three are grammatically correct.